# Best way to integrate Trello with Flowdock?

Tags: trello, flowdock

We're interested in Trello for game development. We're using Flowdock for our team inbox and chat, and would like all card changes in our Trello organization to trigger notifications in Flowdock. Flowdock can be integrated with other web apps via emails (sent to our team inbox), RSS, or an API. The easiest path would be email, but it appears that Trello only sends email notifications for a small subset of card changes (if you were personally added to a card, invited to something, etc.).

Is there a way to trigger Trello email for all card changes?
Otherwise, is the API the best way to integrate with an external app like Flowdock?

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to do this might be with [this Zap](https://zapier.com/zapbook/trello/flowdock/1684/flowdock-message-for-trello-card-activity/) from Zapier.

It will post a message to Flowdock for any new Trello card activity (which is essentially card changes).

[image: Trello to Flowdock]

*Disclaimer: I am a founder at Zapier, but this is exactly what I'd do even if I wasn't.*

Answer (score 2):

The [Trello API](http://trello.com/api) is definitely the best way to do this. We're also working on a [plug-in architecture](https://trello.com/card/plug-in-architecture/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1025) that will help this a lot.